# Pasar a funcion typescript codigo de html

Tags: typescript, entrada

Tengo un código que me pasa de input a input automaticamente cuando llega a maxlength y lo que queria era pasarlo a una función, mi poco conocimiento de ts o js hace que no sepa por donde tirar, dejo lo que tengo

```
<input type="text" id="input10" class="input" placeholder="code" maxlength="4" onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input20.focus()" />

<input type="text" id="input20" class="input" placeholder="code" maxlength="4" onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input30.focus()" />

<input type="text" id="input30" class="input" placeholder="code" maxlength="4" onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength'))" />
```

y en ts

```
inputPass(value) {
  value;

  if (value.length == document.getElementById('input1').getAttribute('maxlength')){
      document.getElementById("input2").focus();

  }

  if (value.length == document.getElementById("input2").getAttribute('maxlength')){
      document.getElementById("input3").focus();

  }

  if (value.length == document.getElementById("input3").getAttribute('maxlength')) {
      document.getElementById("input1").focus();

  }

}
```

entiendo que cuando tenga la funcion bien lo tendre que cambiar por el codigo existente en un onchange

Answer (score 1):

Al final me ha funcionado  haciendolo de esta forma, espero que sirva para alguno mas

```
inputPass(value) {

    if (value.length == document.getElementById('input' + this.value1).getAttribute('maxlength')) {
        if (this.value1 != 3) {

            this.value1++;
            document.getElementById("input" + this.value1).focus();
        }
        else {
            this.value1 = 1;
        }
    }

}
```